# JavaScript Global Variable Re-initialized on PageLoad

Tags: javascript

On Pageload I perform some functions to show data.
My global var is getting re-initialized on the page load and I can't use it to store data. Can someone explain?

```
var busesWithProblems = []; //declared as global - this keeps getting reinitialized 

(function () {
    .... doing stuff
    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        busesWithProblems = something;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS runtime gets reinitialised when you refresh the page. That's the usual state of affairs since browsers where first introduced.

You can use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store data permanently - until the user clears his cache, or [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store data until the user exits your domain

Bear in mind that those 2 methods only store `String`s.

So if you want to save a complex variable you would have to `JSON.stringify()` it when saving, and `JSON.parse()` it when getting it back - [This answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) goes into more detail for this

Comment: This is good. Thanks for the answers. Going ahead with some more coding.

Comment: Consider marking answers that solve your question as accepted. All of your previous questions have unaccepted answers as well

Comment: Yes did it. Thanks again.